# How to implement a CADisplayLink into a for in loop

Tags: ios, swift, for-in-loop, cadisplaylink, animatewithduration

So I am generating a bunch of dot objects using a for in loop and I am animating them across the screen using UIView.animationWithDuration; however, I want to replace the animationWithDurations with CADisplayLinks so that the user is able t interact with the dots (make them tappable). Can someone please show me how this is accomplished? Thanks in advance!!

```
@IBOutlet weak var timerScore: UILabel!


// Set up timer varriables
var count = 0
var timer:NSTimer = NSTimer()

// Declare dot images
let RedDot = UIImage(named: "Red Dot") as UIImage?
let BlueDot = UIImage(named: "Blue Dot") as UIImage?
let YellowDot = UIImage(named: "Yellow Dot") as UIImage?
let GreenDot = UIImage(named: "Green Dot") as UIImage?





override func viewDidLoad() {
    timerScore.text = String(count)
    super.viewDidLoad()



    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTimer"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true



    // Declare delay counter
    var delayCounter:Int = 100000
    var durationCounter:Double = 0

    // loop for 1000 times
    for loopNumber in 0...100 {

        // set up some constants for the animations
        let dotDuration:Double = 4 - durationCounter
        let redDelay = NSTimeInterval(arc4random_uniform(100000) + delayCounter) / 25000
        let blueDelay = NSTimeInterval(arc4random_uniform(100000) + delayCounter) / 25000
        let yellowDelay = NSTimeInterval(arc4random_uniform(100000) + delayCounter) / 25000
        let greenDelay = NSTimeInterval(arc4random_uniform(100000) + delayCounter) / 25000

        let options = UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptions.LayoutSubviews

        //set up some constants for the dots
        let redSize:CGFloat = 54
        let redYPosition : CGFloat = CGFloat( arc4random_uniform(275)) + 54

        let blueSize:CGFloat = 54
        let blueYPosition : CGFloat = CGFloat( arc4random_uniform(275)) + 54

        let yellowSize:CGFloat = 54
        let yellowYPosition : CGFloat = CGFloat( arc4random_uniform(275)) + 54

        let greenSize:CGFloat = 54
        let greenYPosition : CGFloat = CGFloat( arc4random_uniform(275)) + 54

        // create the dots and add them to the view
        let redDot = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
        redDot.setBackgroundImage(RedDot, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        redDot.frame = CGRectMake(0-redSize, redYPosition, redSize, redSize)
        redDot.addTarget(self, action: "redDotTapped:", forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(redDot)


        let blueDot = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
        blueDot.setBackgroundImage(BlueDot, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        blueDot.frame = CGRectMake(0-blueSize, blueYPosition, blueSize, blueSize)
        blueDot.addTarget(self, action: "blueDotTapped:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(blueDot)


        let yellowDot = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
        yellowDot.setBackgroundImage(YellowDot, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        yellowDot.frame = CGRectMake(0-yellowSize, yellowYPosition, yellowSize, yellowSize)
        yellowDot.addTarget(self, action: "yellowDotTapped", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(yellowDot)


        let greenDot = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
        greenDot.setBackgroundImage(GreenDot, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        greenDot.frame = CGRectMake(0-greenSize, greenYPosition, greenSize, greenSize)
        greenDot.addTarget(self, action: "greenDotTapped", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(greenDot)






        // -----------WANT TO REPLACE THESE ANIMATIE WITH DURATIONS WITH CADISPLAYLINKS!!!-------------------

        UIView.animateWithDuration(dotDuration , delay: redDelay, options: options, animations: {

            redDot.frame = CGRectMake(675, redYPosition, redSize, redSize)

            }, completion: nil)



        UIView.animateWithDuration(dotDuration , delay: blueDelay, options: options, animations: {

            blueDot.frame = CGRectMake(675, blueYPosition, blueSize, blueSize)

            }, completion: { animationFinished in blueDot.removeFromSuperview() })



        UIView.animateWithDuration(dotDuration , delay: yellowDelay, options: options, animations: {

            yellowDot.frame = CGRectMake(675, yellowYPosition, yellowSize, yellowSize)

            }, completion: { animationFinished in yellowDot.removeFromSuperview() })



        UIView.animateWithDuration(dotDuration , delay: greenDelay, options: options, animations: {

            greenDot.frame = CGRectMake(675, greenYPosition, greenSize, greenSize)

            }, completion: { animationFinished in greenDot.removeFromSuperview() })










        durationCounter+=0.05
        delayCounter+=50000
    }





}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll only want to add one `CADisplayLink`.

```
var displayLink: CADisplayLink!
override func viewDidLoad() {
  // ...
  for loopNumber in 0...100 {
    // ...
  }
  displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: Selector("moveDots"))
  displayLink.frameInterval = frameInterval
  displayLink.addToRunLoop(NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop(), forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
}

func moveDots() {

  for dot in self.subviews {
    // calculate its new position based on your
    // time delta (displaylink.timestamp) and move it.
  }
}
```

Comment: Do i delete the UIView.animationWithDurations then?

Comment: Yes. Your `moveDots` function will compute and apply the animations.

Comment: So how do you implement it in the loop exactly?

Comment: Calculate your position deltas based on the amount of time that has passed. Because you're animating linearly w.r.t. time, it's a pretty simple calculation of `current.x = (end.x - start.x)/time_passed`.

Comment: Im totally new to CADisplayLinks so I appologize

Comment: The `CADisplayLink` just lets you schedule a method to be called periodically. The `timestamp` property of the link will give you the delta time, so you just need to compute your animation for that interval.